# How can I check if I'm running Ansible from AWX or from command line?

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

Is there a way to know if I'm launching a playbook from AWX or from the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According Ansible Tower documentation [Launch a Job Template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/job_templates.html#launch-a-job-template)

> *Tower automatically adds the following variables to the job environment: ...*
>
> - *`tower_job_launch_type`: The description to indicate how the job was started:*
>
>   - *`manual`: Job was started manually by a user.*

In other words, if specific variables are not set the job was not triggered from Ansible Tower (automatically).

A short example: [`assert` – Asserts given expressions are true](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html) together with [Providing default values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#providing-default-values) can be used to

```yaml
  - name: Check if job was triggered manually or automatically
    assert:
      that:
        - "'manual' not in tower_job_launch_type | default('manual')"
      fail_msg: "Job was triggered manually in Ansible Tower or via Ansible Engine!"
      quiet: true
```